# CUDA atomicAdd with floats

Tags: c++, cuda, floating-point, precision, atomic

I am trying to add all elements of a large vector on the CPU and the GPU and benchmark the result.

My CPU implementation looks like this

```
void reductionCPU(float *result, float *input)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        *result += input[i];
    }
}
```

And my GPU kernel like this:

```
__global__ void reductionKernel(float *result, float *input)
{
    int col = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int index = row * BLOCK_X_NAIVE * BLOCK_COUNT_X + col;

    if (index < SIZE)
    {
        atomicAdd(result, input[index]);
    }
}
```

(Entire minimal working example below)

Both are quite simple but behave a little strange. If I let the CPU and GPU add only numbers the results always match. The output is:

> CPU Time: 22.596495 ms, bandwidth: 3.540372 GB/s
>
> ---block_x:32, block_y:32, dim_x:100, dim_y:98
>
> GPU Time: 30.625248 ms, bandwidth: 2.612224 GB/s CPU result matches
>   GPU result in naive atomic add. CPU: 10000000.000000, GPU:
>   10000000.000000

If I want to add arbitrary floating points, however, the results never match.

> CPU Time: 22.472712 ms, bandwidth: 3.559873 GB/s
>
> ---block_x:32, block_y:32, dim_x:100, dim_y:98
>
> GPU Time: 30.625153 ms, bandwidth: 2.612232 GB/s CPU result does not
>   match GPU result in naive atomic add. CPU: 4996870656.000000, GPU:
>   4996921856.000000, diff:-51200.000000

Changing the amount of elements that are added to something like 50 results in correct calculation in some runs and in others to a false calculation. Increasing the size results in an increased number of incorrect calculations.

I assume that is has something to do with the precision of floating points but that is only a guess.

The same issue occurs if I add only tens or random whole floats between 0 and 10:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    input[i] = floorf(((float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)) * 10);
    //input[i] = 10.0;
}
```

I develop using the latest version of Visual Studio on Windows 10. Further I found that code generation parameter could have an influence as well. I use `compute_30,sm_30`. Replacing the 30 with 60 does not work on my GPU, the result then is always 0.0.

If there is any information missing please let me know.

Here is the entire minimal working code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

cudaError_t reductionWithCuda(float *result, float *input);
__global__ void reductionKernel(float *result, float *input);
void reductionCPU(float *result, float *input);

#define SIZE 10000000
//#define SIZE 50

#define BLOCK_X_NAIVE 32
#define BLOCK_Y_NAIVE 32
#define BLOCK_COUNT_X 100

int main()
{
    int i;
    float *input;
    float resultCPU, resultGPU;
    double cpuTime, cpuBandwidth;

    input = (float*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(float));
    resultCPU = 0;
    resultGPU = 0;

    srand((int)time(NULL));

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        input[i] = ((float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)) * 1000; // random floats between 0 and 1000
        //input[i] = 1.0;
    }

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    reductionCPU(&resultCPU, input);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    cpuTime = (diff.count() * 1000);
    cpuBandwidth = (sizeof(float) * SIZE * 2) / (cpuTime * 1000000);
    printf("CPU Time: %f ms, bandwidth: %f GB/s\n\n", cpuTime, cpuBandwidth);

    reductionWithCuda(&resultGPU, input);

    if (resultCPU != resultGPU)
        printf("CPU result does not match GPU result in naive atomic add. CPU: %f, GPU: %f, diff:%f\n", resultCPU, resultGPU, (resultCPU - resultGPU));
    else
        printf("CPU result matches GPU result in naive atomic add. CPU: %f, GPU: %f\n", resultCPU, resultGPU);

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}

void reductionCPU(float *result, float *input)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        *result += input[i];
    }
}

__global__ void reductionKernel(float *result, float *input)
{
    int col = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int index = row * BLOCK_X_NAIVE * BLOCK_COUNT_X + col;

    if (index < SIZE)
    {
        atomicAdd(result, input[index]);
    }
}

cudaError_t reductionWithCuda(float *result, float *input)
{
    dim3 dim_grid, dim_block;

    float *dev_input = 0;
    float *dev_result = 0;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsed = 0;
    double gpuBandwidth;

    dim_block.x = BLOCK_X_NAIVE;
    dim_block.y = BLOCK_Y_NAIVE;
    dim_block.z = 1;

    dim_grid.x = BLOCK_COUNT_X;
    dim_grid.y = (int)ceil((float)SIZE / (float)(BLOCK_X_NAIVE * BLOCK_Y_NAIVE * BLOCK_COUNT_X));
    dim_grid.z = 1;

    printf("\n---block_x:%d, block_y:%d, dim_x:%d, dim_y:%d\n", dim_block.x, dim_block.y, dim_grid.x, dim_grid.y);

    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_input, SIZE * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_result, sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_input, input, SIZE * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_result, result, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    cudaEventRecord(start);
    reductionKernel << <dim_grid, dim_block >> >(dev_result, dev_input);

    cudaEventRecord(stop);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);

    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed, start, stop);

    gpuBandwidth = (sizeof(float) * SIZE * 2) / (elapsed * 1000000);
    printf("GPU Time: %f ms, bandwidth: %f GB/s\n", elapsed, gpuBandwidth);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(result, dev_result, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dev_input);
    cudaFree(dev_result);

    return cudaStatus;
}
```